# Can't establish site to site VPN with AWS and Sonicwall

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn, sonicwall

I am having trouble getting my site to site VPN working.

On AWS, I have an EC2 instance with a private IP sitting on a VPC with a 192.168.80.0/24. All good there.
I created a Customer Gateway and gave it the IP address of my sonicwall. It says available.
I created a virtual private gateway and connected it to the VPC. It says attached.
I created a site to site VPN and gave it the virtual private gateway and customer gateway. It shows the customer gateway with the IP of the sonicwall and the VPC.  Routing is dynamic. Local IP and Remote P networks look correct. It is in the status of Available.
Then I downloaded the configuration file with type generic.

I then went into my sonicwall and created a new VPN. Selected Site to Site with IKE using Preshared Secret. Copied the IPSEC primary from the configuration file (Virtual Private Gateway). Copied the secret from the downloaded file.
Went to the network tab and selected any address for local, and destination subnet is the subnet of my AWS VPC.
On the proposals tab, I copied all the information from the downloaded file from AWS.

So after all of this, the connection will not turn active. I do not see ANY logs in the sonicwall that address this VPN. Any idea how I can troubleshoot what is going on?

[Sonicwall VPN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLBa3.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with Checking the sonicwall logs to see if you're able to see anything referencing the tunnel you created.  Also maybe a packet capture on the Sonicwall would help identify some issues as well.